# Equivalent for linux mkdir {fileA,fileB} in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, mkdir

I'm just curios. Is there an equivalent for PowerShell that behaves equally to the liunx command listed in the title, i.e.

```
mkdir {folderA, folderB}
```

?

-- edit

the command listed above creates the folders "folderA" and "folderB" (just saw that I wrote file previously. Sorry, my fault) in the current working directory.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How does that Linux command work, exactly? What does `{fileA,fileB}` do? `mkdir` in PowerShell is for creating filesystem folders, not files. If you want to create a file, use `Set-Content`. It looks like you're new here, so keep in mind that you can edit your question with more detail. This is the preferred method for StackOverflow.

Comment: edited the question. But you already gave the answer I was looking for. Does this also work with relative paths?

Comment: ... it does, just tested it

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, and welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Related: [powershell equivalent of linux `mkdir -p`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47357135/712526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mkdir` command in PowerShell is a wrapper for the `New-Item` command. If you want to create multiple folders with a single command, then run:

```
mkdir c:\test,c:\test2;
```

Effectively, because of positional parameters in PowerShell, this passes the array `c:\test,c:\test2` to the `-Path` parameter of the `New-Item` command.

Comment: And don't forget that `md` is an alias to the mkdir function.