# powershell equivalent of linux "mkdir -p"?

Tags: powershell

How can I get the powershell "mkdir" command to act exactly like Linux's `mkdir -p` command?

Under Linux, `mkdir -p` will create nested directories, but only if they don't exist already.  For example, suppose you have a directory `/foo` that you have write permissions for. `mkdir -p /foo/bar/baz` creates bar and baz within bar under existing `/foo`. You run the same command over again, you will not get an error, but nothing will be created.

Comment: Related: [Equivalent for linux `mkdir {fileA,fileB}` in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23737950/712526)

Answer (score 38):

You can ignore errors in PowerShell with the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` parameter (you can shorten this to `-ea 0`). The full PowerShell command is

```
New-Item /foo/bar/baz -ItemType Directory -ea 0
```

You can shorten this to

```
md /foo/bar/baz -ea 0
```

(You can also type `mkdir` instead of `md` if you prefer.)

Note that PowerShell will output the `DirectoryInfo` object it creates when using `New-Item -ItemType Directory` (or the `md` or `mkdir` aliases). If you don't want any output, you can pipe to `Out-Null`.

EDIT: Of course, this is not a feature-for-feature "behaves exactly and precisely the same as `mkdir -p`" command. The point here is to provide information about how to implement similar functionality, with the understanding that different tools likely have different behavioral characteristics.

Comment: Also note that this command will return the directory object either way.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Not true _unless_ you `-Force` it in Pwsh 7.0.0 (not sure about earlier) `clear; $test_dir = 'razzamataz'; $a = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $test_dir -ea 0; $b = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $test_dir -ea 0; $c = New-Item -ItemType Directory -name $test_dir -ea 0 -Force; write-host "a: $a"; write-host "b: $b"; write-host "c: $c"; Remove-Item $test_dir;`

Comment: This command exists with failure error code, so this isn't really an equivalent of `mkdir -p`.

Comment: `New-Item -ItemType Directory` creates intermediate directories if they don't exist. Even the lowly `cmd.exe` `md`/`mkdir` command does that by default. (Of course, I agree that `New-Item -ItemType Directory` doesn't precisely duplicate, feature for feature, the exact details of the behavior of `mkdir -p`. I was aiming for a rough equivalency.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: I stand corrected: `New-Item -ItemType Directory` indeed creates intermediate directories - I guess because the Unix `mkdir` utility does _not_, I assumed `New-Item` wouldn't either. TIL. I've deleted my previous comments, and will restate the parts that do apply in the next comment, so that future readers know what the precise differences are:

Comment: You command signals failure via `$?` if the target directory already exists, whereas the `mkdir` utility reports success in that case. 
Additionally, if the directory already exists, an error message is unnecessarily recorded in  `$Error`; `-ea 4` / `-ErrorAction Ignore` would suppress that error, 
but, either way - again as distinct from Unix `mkdir` -  _unexpected_ errors would be silenced too, such as the inability to create a non-existent target directory due to lack of permissions.

Comment: Also, as noted in my subsequent edit on this answer, my intent in providing this answer is to provide a command that approximates `mkdir -p` in PowerShell; `New-Item -ItemType Directory` does not mimic the precise functionality of `mkdir -p` in every last detail (nor did I intend to say that it does).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Understood, and because it _isn't_ a precise emulation,  I provided supplemental information that tells future readers exactly _in what way it it isn't_, and _what the differences are_. Hope that helps.

Comment: It is genuinely surprising to me that there seems to be an expectation that there would be a PowerShell command that behaves 100% exactly and precisely the same as a different tool. (_Of course_ there will be some behavioral differences; they are different tools. I thought this was obvious without being stated explicitly.)

Comment: (a) It isn't about _expectations of 100% equivalence_: It is about the fact that if an exact emulation isn't possible (as is indeed often to be expected), you would want to know how, precisely, the emulation _differs_ from the original - and that's what my comment provides. Ideally, though, this information should be _part of the answer_, given that comments tend to be ignored. (b) That said, in the case at hand, a _better_ emulation is available that avoids the pitfalls discussed: the use of `-Force` in lieu of `-ea 0`

Comment: "It isn't about expectations of 100% equivalence": It sure seems that way to me, based on some of the comments on this answer. In any case, I think there's enough information in the various answers for even the most pedantic observer to understand the differences.

Comment: Speculating about the _motivation behind_ comments beyond their actual content is unhelpful. Your answer has the most up-votes, so it's important that it be correct and complete, ideally in itself, but if need be via comments. I can only speak to _my_ comments here: Aside from the _meta_ ones (such as this), which explain _why_ the information in the non-meta ones is important (I was hoping that would be self-evident), the non-meta ones provide important information to future readers that clarify the limitations of this answer; also, a better solution is hinted at in my previous meta comment.

Comment: Well, we can agree to disagree about whether what I posted was helpful, but my overall point is that one should not expect 100% equivalence when comparing different tools (unless, of course, the stated objective is to achieve 100% equivalence). So far as I know, nobody ever claimed that PowerShell cmdlets provide 100%, feature-for-feature, precise and exact emulations of other tools. I'll bow out now...

Comment: We can agree that nobody claimed that, notably including me. I tried my best to both provide comments that I believe help future readers and to explain to you, specifically, why that matters. So there wasn't even a  need to speculate about motivation here (except to antagonistically ascribe different motives). It is clear that you didn't hear me, repeatedly, so I'll follow your example.

Comment: "except to antagonistically ascribe different motives" (? - ironically, an attribution of motive) My comments were that I was genuinely surprised that there appeared to be an expectation that PowerShell behaved exactly the same as something else; that's all. If this caused an offense, it wasn't my intention.

Answer (score 16):

The PowerShell equivalent of Unix
`mkdir -p ...`
is
**`$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force ...`**

**`-Force`, like `-p`, implements *desired-state* logic**, which ensures two things:

- It creates *intermediate* directories in the target directory path that may not exist yet *on demand* (`New-Item -Type Directory`, unlike Unix `mkdir`, even does that *by default*).<sup>[1]</sup>
- It *succeeds* if the target directory already exists.

One crucial difference: Unless an error occurs:

- `mkdir -p` produces *no output*.
- By contrast, **`New-Item -Type Directory` outputs a [`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance** representing the target directory. Thus, to emulate the behavior of `mkdir -p`, this output must be *discarded*, which is best done by assigning to `$null` (`$null = New-Item ...`)

**Caveat**:

- On *Windows*, `mkdir` is a *built-in wrapper function* that passes arguments through to [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) `-Type Directory`<sup>[2]</sup>
- On *Unix-like* platforms - in the cross-platform *PowerShell [Core] v6+* edition - `mkdir` is *not* a built-in command, and instead defers to the platform-native external  `mkdir` utility.
- Thus, **if your scripts need to be cross-platform, use `New-Item` explicitly**.

---

Note: **If you *omit* `-Force` and simply *silence errors***, as shown in [Bill Stewart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47357220/45375) (with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, which, however, still *records* the error (in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error)), or with `-ErrorAction Ignore`, which ignores it altogether), you get similar behavior, *except* that:

- **The output behavior will vary situationally:**

  - If the target directory *already exists*, *no* output is produced (because an error occurs that is ignored), whereas if the target directory is *created*, a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance representing it is returned.
- If the target directory already exists, the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) will signal `$false`, even though from the perspective of the desired target state, the prior existence of the target directory should be considered a *success* case (`mkdir -p` indeed indicates success in that case, and so does `New-Item -ItemType Directory` with `-Force`).
- ***Unexpected* errors will be hidden too**, such as the inability to create the directory due to lack of permissions.

  - In other words: Without taking additional actions, you won't know if the command *failed* (you'd have to test its existence explicitly, given that `$?` won't tell you whether a true error occurred).
- A fundamental difference between `New-Item -Type Directory` and Unix `mkdir` is that only the former creates *intermediate* directories on demand *by default*.<sup>[1]</sup>
  `mkdir` only does so with `-p`.

---

<sup>[1] However, you do need `-Force` if you're creating a *file* whose *parent directory* doesn't exist yet. Creating a file requires either *not* passing a `-Type` (aka `-ItemType`) argument or using `-Type File`.</sup>

<sup>[2] More specifically, it is a [proxy (wrapper) function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/) that provides a `-Type Directory` argument *by default*. *Loosely* speaking: it's an alias for `New-Item` that defaults to creating *directories*, via a "baked in" `-Type Directory` argument.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

```
New-Item -Path "c:\some\folder\path" -ItemType Directory
```

Comment: This is enough to imitate the "-p" switch, no need to add ErrorAction.

Comment: @NikolaiKoudelia: No: if the target directory already exists, this will report a (non-terminating) error (in the absence of `-ErrorAction Ignore`, `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, or `-Force`).

Answer (score 3):

What about using `mkdir` with `-Force`? That seems to work for me, it will create all the directories from the specified path, and won't result in an error if they already exist.

```bsh
mkdir path/to/my/target/dir -force
```

Results in:

```bsh
PS > mkdir path/to/my/target/dir -force
    Directory: C:\Users\Sam\path\to\my\target

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          25/09/2020    13:18                dir

# We can check that all directories have been created
PS > tree path
C:\USERS\SAM\PATH
└───to
    └───my
        └───target
            └───dir

# Let's run again now that the directories already exist
PS > mkdir path/to/my/target/dir -force
    Directory: C:\Users\Sam\path\to\my\target

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          25/09/2020    13:20                dir


# And check the result of the previous command
PS > $?
True
```

Comment: Nice, though note that `mkdir` is only an alias for the `New-Item` cmdlet (which is the one that understands `-Force`) on _Windows_; on Unix-like platforms (in PowerShell [Core] v6+), `mkdir` invokes the platform-native, external `mkdir` utility (which only understands `-p`).

Comment: @mklement0 `ni` and `md` are alias for `New-Item`, but `mkdir` is [a function that calls `New-Item`](https://ss64.com/ps/new-item.html).

Comment: @NunoAndré, good point. More specifically, it is a [proxy (wrapper) function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/) that provides a `-Type Directory` argument _by default_. _Loosely_ speaking: it's an alias for `New-Item` that defaults to creating _directories_, via a "baked in" `-Type Directory` argument.