# Use New-Item to make a new directory on Linux?

Tags: linux, powershell, path, environment-variables, mkdir

How do I create a new directory in Linux with Powershell using a variable?

```
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ echo $new_dir
/home/nicholas/mq/ssl
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ ll $new_dir
ls: cannot access '/home/nicholas/mq/ssl': No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ ls /home/nicholas/mq/
ls: cannot access '/home/nicholas/mq/': No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ pwsh dir.ps1 
Get-ChildItem: /home/nicholas/rabbit/dir.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  $new_dir = Get-ChildItem Env:new_dir
     |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find path 'new_dir' because it does not exist.

New-Item: /home/nicholas/rabbit/dir.ps1:5
Line |
   5 |  New-Item -Path $new_dir -ItemType Directory
     |                 ~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$ cat dir.ps1 
$new_dir = Get-ChildItem Env:new_dir

$new_dir

New-Item -Path $new_dir -ItemType Directory 


nicholas@mordor:~/rabbit$
```

It seems to work fine for a hardcoded path string.

See also:

[powershell equivalent of linux "mkdir -p"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47357135/4531180)

Comment: In PowerShell, environment variables are referenced as `$env:varname` rather than `env:varname`.

Comment: example: `$new_dir="mq/ssl";New-Item -Path $new_dir -ItemType Directory`   `$new_dir = Get-ChildItem my_new_dir;$new_dir`